# How to convert matrix (or list) into data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I've got a list with different types in it. They are arranged in matrix form:

```
tmp <- list('a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3)
dim(tmp) <- c(2,3)
tmp
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] 1    2    3
```

That's the form I get it out of another more complex function.

Now I want to transpose it and convert to a data.frame. So I do the following:

```
data <- as.data.frame(t(tmp))
data
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
```

This looks great. But it's got the wrong structure:

```
str(data)
'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1:List of 3
  ..$ : chr "a"
  ..$ : chr "b"
  ..$ : chr "c"
 $ V2:List of 3
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
  ..$ : num 3
```

So how do I get rid of the extra level of lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(data.frame(t(tmp)), unlist), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(df)
# 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ X1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
#  $ X2: num  1 2 3
```

- The inner `data.frame()` call converts the matrix into a two column data.frame, with one `"character"` column and one `"numeric"` column.**
- `lapply(..., unlist)` strips away extra `list()` layer.
- The outer `data.frame()` call converts the resulting list into the data.frame you're after.

** (OK, that intermediate `"character"` column is really of class `"factor"`, but it ends up making no difference in the final result. If you like, you could force it to be have class `"character"` by adding a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` for the inner `data.frame()` call  as well, but I don't think neglecting to do so would ever make a difference...)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the factor of column X1?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck in those "list- and unlist-functions"

Comment: Yeah, "list matrices" can be fairly tricky to deal with. Although they're allowed by the language, my impression is that folks almost always find ways to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

Or this :

```
 as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(tmp),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
```

You can inspect the result:

```
 str(as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(tmp),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)))
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
```

Comment: The problem with this is that by applying `unlist()` "too early", you coerce everything to factor... (which is of course OK if that's what you really want.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien indeed but I avoid using a loop. I can coerce to numeric if needed. Even of it looks that your solution is what the OP is looking for...

Comment: @agstudy The funny part is, that I changed my "complex function" generating tmp so that it returned nums and chars instead of just chars. That's the way I stumbled across this problem. I thought first "let's convert it to nums at the end". But then I thought "there must be a better (or just another) way". Thanks for your help, too!